# Android NFC : Tag lost when APDU command sent to a smart card

Tags: android, tags, nfc, apdu

I am doing an EMV application on Android OS (Samsung Galaxy).

I am able to send several APDU commands without problem but when I am trying to send the internal authentication command. I have this error : Tag lost. Have you got any idea concerning the purpose of this error ? I am not an experimented developer on Android, It may I have forgotten some stuff.

- the command is correct.
- I can replace by another command, it works (I mean I can recover a response).

In which cases a NFC communication can be broken on Android?

Here, you can see my problem when the command is sent :

> D/ECInfoGrabber(14088): Send: 00 88 00 00 04 14 16 67 3D
>   D/OpenGLRenderer(14088): Flushing caches (mode 0)  D/dalvikvm(14088): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 227K, 4% free 14298K/14855K, paused 29ms 
>   I/dalvikvm-heap(14088): Grow heap (frag case) to 14.142MB for
>   115216-byte allocation  D/dalvikvm(14088): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3K, 4%
>   free 14408K/14983K, paused 15ms

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

One possibility is that the response from the card takes more time than the default time-out setting. This often occurs when the card has to do some internal calculations; typically in case of cryptographic operations such as authentication.

You can change the time-out value using [`IsoDep.setTimeout()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/nfc/tech/IsoDep.html#setTimeout%28int%29):

```
 IsoDep iso = IsoDep.get(tag);
 iso.connect();
 iso.setTimeOut(5000); // 5 sec time out
 iso.transceive(apduCommand); // now send your command
```