# mifareClassic.authenticateSectorWithKeyA() - android.nfc.TagLostException: Tag was lost

Tags: android, nfc, mifare

I am getting this exception:

> android.nfc.TagLostException: Tag was lost.
>
> at android.nfc.TransceiveResult.getResponseOrThrow(TransceiveResult.java:48)
>
> at android.nfc.tech.BasicTagTechnology.transceive(BasicTagTechnology.java:151)
>
> at android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic.authenticate(MifareClassic.java:395)
>
> at android.nfc.tech.MifareClassic.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(MifareClassic.java:339)
>
> at com.example.MyTag.a(MyTag.java:870)
>
> at com.example.MyTag.fastRead(MyTag.java:368)

This is my code:

```
Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
MifareClassic mifareClassic = MifareClassic.get(tag);
if (MY_TAG_TIMEOUT_MILLIS != -1) mifareClassic.setTimeout(MY_TAG_TIMEOUT_MILLIS); // have tried -1, 200, 500, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000 and 5000
if (!mifareClassic.isConnected()) mifareClassic.connect();
mifareClassic.authenticateSectorWithKeyA(15, MifareClassic.KEY_DEFAULT); // This line is causing the exception
```

We're getting the problem with tags which I think may not be genuine NXP.

Have tried the suggestion from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776919/android-nfc-tag-lost-when-apdu-command-sent-to-a-smart-card) but it hasn't helped.

Have looked at the [MifareClassic.java source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/56a2301/core/java/android/nfc/tech/MifareClassic.java) but that hasn't given me any clues.

Any idea what the underlying problem is and how to solve?

Comment: Are you sure that the card is a MIFARE Classic 1K or 4K (i.e. not a Mini), that the sector is accessible with key A, and that key A equals `FF FF FF FF FF FF` (KEY_DEFAULT)?

Comment: It's definitely 1K and each sector has the `KEY_DEFAULT` key, but I'm not sure about the authenticity of the chips as the ones I was testing with (which I'm told is from the same batch) were showing up in NXP's TagInfo app as *Unknown Manufacturer* / *Cloned IC*.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem occurs because you need to make the card stay in the range for a few seconds. If you take it away after you just read the card, you get this exception.